# snowflake pivot attribute values into columns in array of objects

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

EDIT: I gave bad example data.  Updated some details and switched out dummy data for sanitized, actual data.

Source system: Freshdesk via Stitch

Table Structure:

```
create or replace TABLE TICKETS (
    CC_EMAILS VARIANT,
    COMPANY VARIANT,
    COMPANY_ID NUMBER(38,0),
    CREATED_AT TIMESTAMP_TZ(9),
    CUSTOM_FIELDS VARIANT,
    DUE_BY TIMESTAMP_TZ(9),
    FR_DUE_BY TIMESTAMP_TZ(9),
    FR_ESCALATED BOOLEAN,
    FWD_EMAILS VARIANT,
    ID NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
    IS_ESCALATED BOOLEAN,
    PRIORITY FLOAT,
    REPLY_CC_EMAILS VARIANT,
    REQUESTER VARIANT,
    REQUESTER_ID NUMBER(38,0),
    RESPONDER_ID NUMBER(38,0),
    SOURCE FLOAT,
    SPAM BOOLEAN,
    STATS VARIANT,
    STATUS FLOAT,
    SUBJECT VARCHAR(16777216),
    TAGS VARIANT,
    TICKET_CC_EMAILS VARIANT,
    TYPE VARCHAR(16777216),
    UPDATED_AT TIMESTAMP_TZ(9),
    _SDC_BATCHED_AT TIMESTAMP_TZ(9),
    _SDC_EXTRACTED_AT TIMESTAMP_TZ(9),
    _SDC_RECEIVED_AT TIMESTAMP_TZ(9),
    _SDC_SEQUENCE NUMBER(38,0),
    _SDC_TABLE_VERSION NUMBER(38,0),
    EMAIL_CONFIG_ID NUMBER(38,0),
    TO_EMAILS VARIANT,
    PRODUCT_ID NUMBER(38,0),
    GROUP_ID NUMBER(38,0),
    ASSOCIATION_TYPE NUMBER(38,0),
    ASSOCIATED_TICKETS_COUNT NUMBER(38,0),
    DELETED BOOLEAN,
    primary key (ID)
);
```

Note the variant field, "custom_fields".  It undergoes an unfortunate transformation between the api and snowflake.  The resulting field contains an array of 3 or more objects, each one a custom field.  I do not have the ability to change the data format.  Examples:

```
# values could be null
[
  {
    "name": "cf_request",
    "value": "none"
  },
  {
    "name": "cf_related_with",
    "value": "none"
  },
  {
    "name": "cf_question",
    "value": "none"
  }
]

# or values could have a combination of null and non-null values
[
  {
    "name": "cf_request",
    "value": "none"
  },
  {
    "name": "cf_related_with",
    "value": "none"
  },
  {
    "name": "cf_question",
    "value": "concern"
  }
]

# or they could all have non-null values
[
  {
    "name": "cf_request",
    "value": "issue with timer"
  },
  {
    "name": "cf_related_with",
    "value": "timer stopped"
  },
  {
    "name": "cf_question",
    "value": "technical problem"
  }
]
```

I would essentially like to pivot these into fields in a select query where the name attribute's value becomes a column header.  Making the output similar to the following:

```
+----+------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id |    cf_request    | cf_related_with |    cf_question    |      all_other_fields       |
+----+------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------------------+
|  5 | issue with timer | timer stopped   | technical problem | more data about this ticket |
|  6 | hq               | laptop issues   | some value        | more data                   |
|  7 | a thing          | about a thing   | about something   | more data                   |
+----+------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Is there a function that searches the values of array objects and returns objects with qualifying values? Something like:

```
select
id,
get_object_where(name = 'category', value) as category,
get_object_where(name = 'subcategory', value) as category,
get_object_where(name = 'subsubcategory', value) as category
from my_data_table
```

Unfortunately, PIVOT requires an aggregate function, I tried using min and max, but only get a return of null values.  Something similar to this approach would be great if there is another syntax to do it that doesn't require aggregation.

```
with arr as (
  select
  id, 
  cs.value:name col_name, 
  cs.value:value col_value
  from my_data_table,
    lateral flatten(input => custom_fields) cs
)
select 
*
from arr 
pivot(col_name for col_value in ('category', 'subcategory', 'subsubcategory')
as p (id, category, subcategory, subsubcategory);
```

It is possible to use the following approach, but it is flawed in that any time a new custom field is added I have to add cases to account for new positions within the array.

```
select
    id, 
    case 
      when custom_fields[0]:name = 'cf_request' then custom_fields[0]:value
      when custom_fields[1]:name = 'cf_request' then custom_fields[1]:value
      when custom_fields[2]:name = 'cf_request' then custom_fields[2]:value
      when custom_fields[2]:name = 'cf_request' then custom_fields[3]:value
      else null
    end cf_request,
    case 
      when custom_fields[0]:name = 'cf_related_with' then custom_fields[0]:value
      when custom_fields[1]:name = 'cf_related_with' then custom_fields[1]:value
      when custom_fields[2]:name = 'cf_related_with' then custom_fields[2]:value
      when custom_fields[2]:name = 'cf_related_with' then custom_fields[3]:value
      else null
    end cf_related_with,
    case 
      when custom_fields[0]:name = 'cf_question' then custom_fields[0]:value
      when custom_fields[1]:name = 'cf_question' then custom_fields[1]:value
      when custom_fields[2]:name = 'cf_question' then custom_fields[2]:value
      when custom_fields[2]:name = 'cf_question' then custom_fields[3]:value
      else null
    end cf_question,
    created_at
from my_db.my_schema.tickets;
```

Comment: I've answered below, but did want to comment that it's a shame that your source data doesn't understand the concept of JSON name/value pairs.  This would've been a straight select if they had.  Seems like you know that, though.  :-)

Comment: The freshdesk API represents the data well.  I'm using Stitch to copy the data into Snowflake and the Freshdesk integration in Stitch (which I think is the Singer.io tap-freshdesk)  converts the data into this format.

Comment: I wrote a Snowflake stored procedure to get dynamics pivots inside Snowflake, check
https://hoffa.medium.com/dynamic-pivots-in-sql-with-snowflake-c763933987c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you almost had it.  You just need to add a max() or min() around your col_name.  As you stated, it needs an aggregate function, and something like max() or min() will work here, since it is aggregating on the name/value pairs that you have.  If you have 2 subcategory values, for example, it'll pick the min/max value.  From your example, that doesn't appear to be an issue, so it'll always choose the value you want.  I was able to replicate your scenario with this query:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT parse_json('[{"name": "category","value": "Bikes"},{"name": "subcategory","value": "Mountain Bikes"},{"name": "subsubcategory","value": "hardtail bikes"}]')::VARIANT as field_var
    ),
arr as (
  select
  seq,
  cs.value:name::varchar col_name, 
  cs.value:value::varchar col_value
  from x,
    lateral flatten(input => x.field_var) cs
)
select 
*
from arr
pivot(max(col_value) for col_name in ('category','subcategory','subsubcategory')) as p (seq, category, subcategory, subsubcategory);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this question.  I meant to take away unnecessary details by creating an example.  I stripped away too much.  I am updating with actual data and schema.  I'm really sorry for the inconvenience to you.

Comment: So, you essentially want a dynamic way to do what I've shown statically.  I think you could do that with a Javascript Stored Procedure where you get all of the possible values within you JSON field(s) and then dynamically generate the SQL that I have above.  I've done something similar in Python in the past, but JS isn't my strong suit.  Pretty sure its possible.

Comment: I was not able to return accurate results with pivot using min() or max().  I'll look at it again.  I"m sure I could figure out the JS to dynamically generate the query.  I'll accept the answer as soon as I can get the pivot to return correct results.

Comment: @StephenLloyd Do you have cases where you have multiple values for `col_value` on the same `col_name` on the same record?  If not, min/max should work.  Feel free to post what you are seeing, if you need help.

Comment: I had col_value and col_name flipped in the pivot().  As a result I was getting all NULLs.  Thank you for the assist.

Comment: Also if you are just using min() or max() to pick the unique (or an arbitrary) value for a column, you can use the Snowflake aggregate function `any()` instead

Comment: I wrote a Snowflake stored procedure to get dynamics pivots inside Snowflake, check
https://hoffa.medium.com/dynamic-pivots-in-sql-with-snowflake-c763933987c