# Snowflake how to loop over an array of objects and merge data into related tables without moving the array into a temporary table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an array having the following structure:

```
var array = [
    {
        "dim_label": "...",
        "dim_name": "...",
        "field_label": "...",
        "field_name": "..."
    },
    {
        "dim_label": "...",
        "dim_name": "...",
        "field_label": "...",
        "field_name": "..."
    }
]
```

I need to loop over it in a Snwoflake procedure and merge necessary rows into their related tables. My current procedure is reading from a CSV staged file and doing the merge like so:

```
var field_label_query = "MERGE INTO SAT_FIELD AS D "+
                "USING (SELECT T.$"+FIELD_LABEL_POSITION+", T.$"+FIELD_ONA_POSITION+" FROM "+FILE_FULL_PATH+"(FILE_FORMAT=>"+FILE_FORMAT_NAME+") T) ST "+
                "ON D.FIELD_NAME_HASH_KEY = md5(ST.$"+FIELD_ONA_POSITION+") "+
                "WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN "+
                "INSERT (SAT_FIELD_HASH_KEY, LOAD_DT, LOAD_END_DT, RECORD_SRC, FIELD_LABEL_NAME, FIELD_NAME_HASH_KEY) "+
                "VALUES(MD5(ST.$"+FIELD_LABEL_POSITION+"), current_timestamp(), NULL, 'ONA', ST.$"+FIELD_LABEL_POSITION+", md5(ST.$"+FIELD_ONA_POSITION+"))";
```

Is it possible to do the merge without adding the array data into a temporary table?

Comment: Have you tried just using a `LATERAL FLATTEN` of the array?  You could use a CTE inside your USING select.

Comment: What is CTE in snowflake ?

Comment: @MikeWalton hope you can help on it sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution using [the answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59966415/snowflake-pivot-attribute-values-into-columns-in-array-of-objects):

```
with cte_dim_fields as ( 
    select parse_json('JSON.stringify(dim_field_array)+')::VARIANT as field_var 
), cte_arr_to_table as ( 
    select cs.value:dim_label as dim_label, 
    cs.value:dim_name as dim_name, 
    cs.value:field_label as field_label, 
    cs.value:field_name as field_name 
    from cte_dim_fields, 
    lateral flatten(input=>cte_dim_fields.field_var) cs 
) 
select dim_label, dim_name, field_label, field_name from cte_arr_to_table;
```

To do an insert with a CTE:

```
INSERT INTO my_table with cte_dim_fields as ( 
    select parse_json('JSON.stringify(dim_field_array)+')::VARIANT as field_var 
), cte_arr_to_table as ( 
    select cs.value:dim_label as dim_label, 
    cs.value:dim_name as dim_name, 
    cs.value:field_label as field_label, 
    cs.value:field_name as field_name 
    from cte_dim_fields, 
    lateral flatten(input=>cte_dim_fields.field_var) cs 
) 
select dim_label, dim_name, field_label, field_name from cte_arr_to_table;
```